# django-admin-sortable not saving order of the existing objects

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use django-admin-sortable 2.1.2 and django 1.11.

The problem is that the order is not saving when I try to change it from my admin panel. I think this may be due to already existing model instances.

Here is the part of my current code:

```
// models.py
class Category(SortableMixin):
    name = models.CharField(
        _('name'), 
        max_length=150,
    )
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        db_index=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('categories')
        ordering = ['order']


// admin.py
class CategoryAdmin(SortableModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'name',
        )
        sortable = 'order'
```

The default value is set as 0 because of already existing objects. I tried to change their order manually in shell console but it did not help.
I want to avoid deleting my objects and creating them again.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use another class to inheritance from in my `admin.py` file.

Instead of:

```
from suit.admin import SortableModelAdmin
class CategoryAdmin(SortableModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'name',
        )
        sortable = 'order'
```

I use:

```
from adminsortable.admin import SortableAdmin
class CategoryAdmin(SortableAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            'name',
        )
        sortable = 'order'
```

It works a little different but the effect is satisfying for me and solves my problem.